# How can I call the Score() function from TargetHit script to UpdateUI script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just a quick question of How to call a `Score()` function from `TargetHit script` to UpdateUI? UpdateUI will show the score to Canvas.

Below is the snippet of the 2 scripts.

TargetHit Script

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) 
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Green")
        {
            AddScoreGreen();
        }
        else if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Yellow")
        {
            AddScoreYellow();
        }
        else
        {
            NoScore();
        }
        Destroy(collider.gameObject);
    }

    public int AddScoreGreen()
    {
        return ScoreIncrease + 100;
    }

    public int AddScoreYellow()
    {
        return ScoreIncrease + 50;
    }

    public int NoScore()
    {
        return ScoreIncrease = 0;
    }
}
```

UpdateUI script

```
private readonly TargetHit targetHit;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    scoreGreen.text = targetHit.GetComponent<TargetHit>().AddScoreGreen().ToString();
    playerLevelLabel.text = "Level 1";
    timerLabel.text = FormatTime(GameManager.Instance.TimePassed);        
}

private string FormatTime(float timeInSeconds)
{
    return string.Format("Time: " + "{0}:{1:00}", Mathf.FloorToInt(timeInSeconds / 60), Mathf.FloorToInt(timeInSeconds % 60));
}
```

`ScoreGreen()` method stalled the Unity with immediate paused icon is presses and no error showing from unity.

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First You are not actually increasing your score like that:

```
 public int AddScoreGreen()
 {
     return ScoreIncrease + 100;
 }
```

You are just returning the `ScoreIncrease` with 100 added to the return value. `ScoreIncrease` is not modified.

You probably want this:

```
public void AddScoreGreen()
{
    ScoreIncrease += 100;
}
```

Next, this seems wrong:

```
targetHit.GetComponent<TargetHit>()
```

You already declared a variable of type TargetHit above:

```
private readonly TargetHit targetHit;
```

Make it public:

```
public TargetHit targetHit;
```

And then in Inspector, drag the Object with the script into the slot of "UpdateUI" Script.

Then you should be able to call it:

```
scoreGreen.text = targetHit.getScore();
```

For that, you should implement the "getter" function:

```
public int getScore ()
{
    return ScoreIncrease;
}
```

And maybe rename ScoreIncrease to "score_green" and add more variables for other colors.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections on the code. I am getting the error in running those. Perhaps I will start from the small requirements that may resolve some bits and pieces of error.